# Production Server for React Redux Starter Kit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using the React Redux Starter Kit from DaveZuko, and am stuck on how to create production server to serve the compile client side code.Ideally I would just like to use the Koa server and move it to production, but can't find out how to do that.

All relevant code is unchanged from the repository here: https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit

Does anybody know how to compile a product server for this?

Comment: After running `npm run compile` you get a `dist` folder with an `index.html` file.. from there you serve it like anything else koa, nginx, express etc. which part are you specifically having trouble with?

Comment: It's more about how to link the production server into the rest of the pipeline. Ideally I would like npm run compile to produce a production version of the Koa server. Otehrwise I need to have a separate 'server.js' to serve the file, add HSTS etc.

Comment: It's also not clear to me how to extend the starter kit with a server support, so I could add server routes (e.g. `/api`) and access them from a browser.

Comment: Have you sorted this out?

Comment: I've created my own version of this starter kit that basically extends this one with SSR / Universal rendering. It can run as a production server too. If interested, check out: https://github.com/janoist1/universal-react-redux-starter-kit

Answer (score 1):

I did try to use davezuko's starter kit, but it was really hard to follow what those configuration files really did and messed them up when trying to install packages that were missing.

I also tried facebook's create-react-app, but that was really complex too when you run the eject command, so I gave up and created my own starter kit http://redux-minimal.js.org/ . I has the minimum amount of packages that lets you build rich real-word apps, but doesn't have the cluttered configuration boilerplate that other starter kits have.

Now, answering your question, with redux minimal, you just do "npm run build-prod" and it compiles the css and js files for the production environment, minified and ready to go. Then you just copy the public folder which contains the html file too, paste to what ever server you want, and then call the index.html url and it works.